# Below code is not hitting Assertion

Tags: c++

I am experimenting with VERIFY. I have written a sample code where I have declared a struct with a pointer to integer. I am assignment one structure variable to another. When the scope of main ends, destructor is called for both the objects. I have written code in the destructor to delete the pointer and assigning it to null. I observed that the pointer in another structure object is not becoming null as expected(Since the default copy constructor does shallow copy. Please help.

```
// DebuggingTools.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Precompiled.h"
#include <crtdbg.h>
#define ASSERT _ASSERTE

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define VERIFY ASSERT
#else
#define VERIFY(expression) (expression)
#endif

struct Verify
{
    int* ptr;
    ~Verify()
    {
        VERIFY(DEL(&ptr));
    }
    bool DEL(int** p)
    {
       if (*p != NULL)
       {
           delete *p;
           *p = NULL;
           return true;
       }
       else return false;
    }
 };
 auto main() -> int
 {
     Verify mypoint;
     Verify hispoint;
     mypoint.ptr = new int(15);
     hispoint = mypoint;
 }
```

Comment: side note: don't use ALLCAPITALS names for a member function (`DEL` in your case): where I read `VERIFY(DEL(&ptr));` I started looking for a `#define DEL something`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), and apparently think that member variables for different instances of a class is connected.

That means when you copy the pointer with

```
hispoint = mypoint;
```

you have two *independent* pointers, both pointing to the same memory.

When one of the object go out of scope the memory is deleted. Then the other memory goes out of scope and you attempt to delete the very same memory again.

The two pointer member variables are different. There is one distinct member variable instance per object, and they are not related or connected to each other in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Each object has its own pointer to int. Your assignment to nullptr in one object does not assign to nullptr the pointer in another object. Finally you have UB double dynamic memory freeing.
If you want to share the pointer between all objects of the same class, declare the static pointer to int like

```
static int* ptr;
```

And define it outside the class like

```
int* Verify::ptr = nullptr;
```